# Making an API call in Javascript - new call at each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

Here's what I want to achieve:

I have an element on a webpage, let's call is *storm*
Every time the user clicks on the *storm* link, I want the following:

- perform an API call which parameters are pre-defined BUT with the *storm* string as one of them
- store the result (the API generates a JSON file) somewhere
- parse the result with one method or another.

I have no problem parsing the JSON returned, but I would like to know how to do the first two steps. 
NB: I use JS more than jQuery, but I'm not nazi on this.

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT: thanks @ema
I've got a XHR model, attached under here.
Can you help me identify where I have to add my API url (from what I've understood, what is before the first question mark), and how to add to it the pre-defined parameters and the custom parameter (a string, containing *storm* for example)?

Thanks again

```
function XHR(url, method, data, onsuccess, onfailure, onprogress, onload, onabort) {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Ten seconds is ought to be enough for anybody.
var xhrtimeout = setTimeout(onfailure, 10000);
request.addEventListener("progress", onprogress, false);
request.addEventListener("load", onprogress, false);
request.addEventListener("error", onfailure, false);
request.addEventListener("abort", onabort, false);
request.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (e) {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      clearTimeout(xhrtimeout);
      onsuccess(request.responseText);
   } else {
    onfailure(e);
   }
 }
});

 request.open(method, url, true);
 request.send(data);
}


function getJSONAndParse(url, allDone) {
  XHR(url, "GET", null, function(data) {
    allDone(JSON.parse(data));
  }, function() {
    alert("error");
 });
}

getJSONAndParse("http://lalala.com/json", function(parsedJSON) {
  alert(parseJSON[0].name);
  console.log(parseJSON);
});
```

Comment: `$.post` or `XMLHttpRequest` should do the trick. Exact call and instructions depend on the API you are dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XMLHttpRequest, something like this:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open("POST", "api/url", true);
r.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var json = r.responseText;
  // parse your json here
};
r.send("storm=value_of_storm&another_param=value_of_whatever");
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you @ema. Just edited the question with more precisions.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understood..

To call an API from JQuery is very simple, and you cand use $.ajax (most complete) or $.post (simplest)

both you call on the click event that you can bind in $(document).ready with

```
$(document.ready(function(){
    $('.mybuttons').off('click');//to only hit once if you have Postbacks
    $('.mybuttons').on('click', myapicall);
});
```

example with $.ajax:

```
function myapicall(){
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
        // a 'Loading' 
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'URL-OF-API',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { stormvalue: 'the sorm value you want to send to API'},
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (json) {
        try {
            json = JSON.parse(json.d);
            // now you have a json object to play with, and if its a string, then you can """save""" using eg. input hidden

        } catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);//show the error parsing json
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
        alert(r); // show the error of callback
    },
    complete: function (json) {
        alert('sucess!');
    }
});
}
```

example with $.post

```
function myapicall(){
$.post('URL-OF-API', { stormvalue: 'the sorm value you want to send to API'},
    function (json) {
        try {
            json = JSON.parse(json.d);
            // now you have a json object to play with, and if its a string, then you can "save" using eg. input hidden

        } catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);//show the error parsing json
        }
    }
);
}
```

Hope I can help you, and sorry for bad english, ;-)